# Toggle list items on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to build a list, where when clicks on a dt, the corresponding dd would appear, and when they reclicks on that dt the dd slides up.

The first dd always stays unless the user clicks on it.

The problem is, when a user clicks on a dt, all the dd's appear.

[Fiddle demo here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WLW8q/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.nextUntil` on clicked `dt` like below,

```
(function () {
    var dd = $('dd');
    dd.filter(':lt(3)').addClass('show'); //add show to first 3
    dd.filter(':nth-child(n+6)').addClass('hide'); //add hide to rest

    $('dt').on('click', function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('dt').toggleClass('show hide');
    })

})();
```

**DEMO:** http://fiddle.jshell.net/2MrxM/

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for the 1st dt. 
That too must slide up if clicked upon.

Comment: @SiddharthPatel Try now, you need to add `show` to first 3 for toggle to work.

Answer (score 0):

That ought to do it. Updated your [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WLW8q/3/), too.

```
(function () {
    var dd = $('dd');
    dd.filter(':nth-child(n+6)').addClass('hide');

    $('dt').on('click', function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('dt').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').addClass('show');
    })

})();
```